# arguments[0].click() not working for select option in selenium

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am using selenium for the web application automation.

 I stuck in one point,I am using `.ExecuteScript()` to perform some action like to click on a link and for that am using :-

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(),'Login to the Demo')]")));
```

[**Note** : for every click-able element am using ,this approach because click-able element may be hidden or not visible in web page]
But this approach is not working for 
 `<select> <option>item<option> .. </select>`

I am using below code clicking on one of the select option :

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@id='form_switcher']/option[5]")));
```

but nothing is happening nor giving any error/exception.

--**Edit start**--

But if I use without `ExecuteScript()` then its work fine:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@id='form_switcher']/option[5]")).Click();
```

--**Edit end**--

[**Note** : I am using click to select options so that it fire the change event.]

So can anyone please explain me how to click on the select option using `((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript`


Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you doing it this why? Selenium has a `SelectElement` class that handles `select` elements and their `options`.....

Comment: @Arran : but when dropdown is not visible (consider `select` is get visible on mouseover on some menu) then it will throw exception.

Comment: If the entire `<select>` element is hidden how would the user interact with it as normal? Do you mean the `<option>` of the `<select>` is hidden? If yes, then use the `SelectElement()` class to handle it as normal.

Comment: @MarkRowlands : the entier `<select>` element is on a `<div>` which get visible on mouseover only.

Comment: You'll likely have to use `ActionChains()` to 'mouse over' the `<div>` before you can 'see' and interact with your `<select>` element.

Comment: @MarkRowlands : you are right Mark, but i want a one command that works for visible as well as for hidden `<select>` element that's why i want to simulate click event on `option` of `select` element using javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dropdowns you need to select and not click.  You should return the element and then perform a `element.SelectedIndex = 5;`

If you need to modify your javascript to get the element via javascript instead of selenium you can utilize the `document.evaluate` located https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.evaluate?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.evaluate

so then you return an element that represents your select element and then set the `SelectedIndex` value.

I believe this is correct...

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("var element = document.evaluate(\"//select[@id='form_switcher']\", document.documentElement, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null); element.SelectedIndex = 5;  return element.fireEvent('event specifics go here')");
```

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/HTML/UsingthefireEventMethod.htm

Comment: I am using click to select because i want to fire change event attached with that `select` element. And `element.SelectedIndex = 5;` will only change the selected item but won't fire change event attached with that.

Comment: Updated... use the `element.fireEvent()`  I put a reference in there as well.