# Selenium: get WebElement from executing javascript

Tags: python, selenium

```
def get_element():
    return browser.execute_script("return document.getElementById('dsq')")
```

however `get_element()` keeps on returning None. I was expecting it to give me a Selenium WebElement. When I execute that javascript on the browser, it gives me DOM node elements.

Comment: Why on earth are you finding an element by ID through JavaScript instead of native Selenium code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make a javascript DOM object equal a python selenium element.  It won't be able to automatically convert like that.  You would have to have code to build a Selenium version of the element from the returned object in the javascript version which you returned.  Personally I would do whatever you want on the element with straight javascript and return simple types of objects that can be auto-converted (i.e. string, int, arrays of string/int etc...).

Here is a post with some help along those lines:
[arguments[0].click() not working for select option in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290100/arguments0-click-not-working-for-select-option-in-selenium/25292430#25292430)

If you do want to be able to execute javascript and get a DOM object and convert that to a Selenium element I would suggest that you familiarize yourself with the Selenium code base and how it does it's DOM selection specifically and how it casts that into the IWebElement interface implementation.  https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/#git%2Fpy

Comment: I am using python however

Comment: Yes, but the other post is mostly about javascript which you already have the python code to execute the javascript from if you go that route.  Otherwise the code link is to the python code project.