# How to perform a JavaScript click using WebdriverIO v5?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I'am attempting to perform a JavaScript click on a checkbox using the addCommand which is provided by WebdriverIO v5 (Please note I do not intend to use WebdriverIO's standard click')

I have created the following command and added it to my wdio file:

```
browser.addCommand("jsClick", function(selector) {
    browser.execute("arguments[0].click();", selector);
});
```

Attempting to use the above command on a specific element, with no luck:

```
const clickByXpathSelector = $("//div[@id='checkboxes']//input[@value='option-1']");

browser.jsClick("//div[@id='checkboxes']//input[@value='option-1']");
clickByXpathSelector.jsClick();
```

Using the below command, I seem to be getting the following exception:

```
browser.jsClick("//div[@id='checkboxes']//input[@value='option-1']");
clickByXpathSelector.jsClick();


unknown error: arguments[0].click is not a function
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: This may help https://webdriver.io/docs/customcommands.html#overwriting-element-commands Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290100/arguments0-click-not-working-for-select-option-in-selenium

Comment: thanks @Rahul L I'm struggling to find a solution to click on a checkbox, I would of expected the default webdriverio click to work but cant find a way round it :/

Comment: If your checkbox is accompanied with a label, try clicking the label. This would toggle the checkbox value. const label = $('label[for="my-checkbox"]');

label.click();

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
const element = $("#submit");
browser.execute("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Hey your code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call *arguments[0]* since it's JS, you need just execute a function over it. So `"arguments[0].click();", element` comes to `function(element) {element.click();}`

Here's an example for wdio 5 command in TypeScript:

```js
browser.addCommand(
  "jsClick",
  function(this: any) {
    browser.execute(function(element) {
      element.click();
    }, this);
  },
  true,
);
```

Comment: how we can use this ? tried
 jsClick(element ) and browser.jsClick(element) but both can not identify jsClick

Comment: element.jsClick()

Comment: Getting error
Property 'jsClick' does not exist on type 'Element'. Did you mean 'click'?ts(2551)

When using 
 const elementHandle = await driver.$(picklistItemX);
 await elementHandle.jsClick();